# SQLite3 and PHP: sorting entries by datetime

Tags: php, datetime, sqlite

I have a SQLite3 DB with entries storing sensor readings. Each row in the table looks like this:

```
time                | temp1 | humid1 | temp2 | humid2
2013-12-07 23:15:51 | 26.06 | 16.29  | 22.24 | 17.55
```

where the first entry is the date, and the following ones are sensor data.
Now what I need to do is, using PHP, get the most recent 30 minutes of readings. I only want data that's less than 30 minutes old, since it's possible that data collection wasn't running and I would then get old data if I just selected the first bunch of values.

I can think of 2 ways I could do this:
Is there some way in SQLite to do something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time < (time-30 minutes)
```

The other thing I could do is grab the first 300 values (equivalent to 30 minutes)
and then compare the year, month, day, hour, and minute myself. The problem is, I don't know how to extract those from the PHP variable I get when I do just

```
SELECT * FROM table  ORDER BY time DESC limit 300
```

So let's say I get a row (in PHP) called $row, where the time is $row['time'].
How would I go about extracting the years, months... etc. from that and comparing it to the current time?

Comment: I personally prefer to store time in an bigint format and use epoc time.  This is good because it avoids timezone conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time > datetime('now', '-30 minutes');
```

Comment: Tested this and works! `sqlite> select datetime('now') > datetime('now', '-30 minutes');
1`

Comment: Excellent, thank you! The exact syntax is:
 `SELECT * FROM table WHERE time > datetime('now', '-30 minutes', 'localtime');`